# Element gets blurry after transition or animation

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-safari

After I use CSS `transition` or `animation` that includes `rotate` the whole containing div gets a little bit blurry,
I read that it is some kind of side effect from redrawing the element, but is there a way to prevent it?

```
.toggle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    bottom: 7px;
    right: 94px;
    z-index: 200;
    background: transparent url("../img/handle-open.png") no-repeat;

    -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.91,0.00,1.00,1.00);
       -moz-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.91,0.00,1.00,1.00);
            transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.91,0.00,1.00,1.00);
}

.toggle-closed {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

I tries to achieve the same with `animate` and got the same result

[image]

**Update:** I noticed something weird happening - in chrome, when the animation runs the element gets blurry and when the animation stops it return to normal,
on iOS however it happens the other way around - the image is clear while animated but gets blurry when completed! another weird @$$ bug!?

Comment: post some code, be alittle more specific

Comment: What happens when you try this in normal mac safari?

Comment: @Omar Abdelhafith it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Ive seen issues such as this before after doing animations. Check the dimensions of the object after the transition, it may very well have changed in size by a few points causing blurry-ness. i,e:

Before transition: 36x36
 After Transition:  36.2 x 36.8

Comment: what is also weird is that the circle has it's own div but somehow the whole containing div is affected.